# create multiple objects using writable nested serializers in django rest framework 3

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

In drf3 you can now implement a writable nested serializer by overriding the create() method and handling validated_data yourself

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
    return user
```

What if profile was a **to many** relationship and the validated_data would actually contain **multiple profiles**. How would I create multiple related objects in create?

Comment: If you know it actually contains the data you think you can just create them in a loop

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: i dont know how the data is given as i havent upgraded to 3 yet, but if it is a list then a normal for-loop would do the job

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by krs the answer is the following:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    profiles_data = validated_data.pop('profiles')
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for profile_data in profiles_data:
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user,**profile_data)
    return user
```